# Passport.js treating azure-ad authentication link as relative, returns 404 on attempted login

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-azure-ad

We are using `passport-azure-ad` to allow users in our domain to log into an internal node app with their Microsoft AD credentials. I had this system working previously with just 1 node app, but now we are trying a new system where we have 2 separate apps running locally with PM2 and serving them up through IIS under the same URL but you access each app like this:
*mywebsite.com/app1* OR *mywebsite.com/app2*

Only the second app needs authentication. The issue I am running into is when you hit login, the `passport.authenticate` method seems to be trying to redirect to a relative authorization link:
**mywebsite.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize**
, rather than the actual authorization endpoint which is:
**[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize)**

Does anyone know why this may be and what I could do to stop passport from treating the auth endpoint like a relative link? This causes a 404 every time a user hits /login because **/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize** route doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RIP to anyone finding this in the future.

For me, the solution was as follows:

- Open IIS and select your SERVER (not site), then open **Application Request Routing Cache** under IIS
  [image]
- On the far right Actions pane, select **Server Proxy Settings...** under Proxy
  [image]
- UNCHECK **Reverse rewrite host in response headers** checkbox under Proxy Setting, and make sure you hit Apply on right pane!
  [image]
- It is important to note I also had to update my entry point app.js to use extended url encoding: `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`, as well as updating the redirect URLs in your authentication routes. Azure will also need to know your redirect URIs.